# How can I get all elements from certain (multiple) classes using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I want to get all fields that have this class: "requiredField Validate".

Code sample:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" class="requiredField X"> Text1
<input type="text" class="requiredField Y"> Text2
<input type="text" class="requiredField Validate"> Text3
<input type="text" class="requiredField Validate"> Text4
<input type="text" class="requiredField Z"> Text5
</form>
```

How can I do this using jQuery?

I tried to do this and had no success:

```
$('.requiredField.Validate').each(function() {...
$('form.myForm.Validate')
$('.requiredField Validate')
```

Comment: Your first method works http://jsfiddle.net/atZPn/9/, must be something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way,

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/LRL3v/)**

```
$('.requiredField.Validate')
```

Comment: In the first place, it was not working but now it's ok. Thks by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('.requiredField.Validate'); // Will select elements that has both classes.
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/VNrpe/), see the console.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$('.requiredField').filter('.Validate');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as in CSS

```
$('.requiredField .Validate')
```

which means every .Validate concerning .requiredField is true

In difference

```
$('.requiredField, .Validate')
```

which means `.Validate` or `.requiredField`.

Comment: it means: Take `.Validate` elements below `.requireField` elements. This will not catch elements with both classes

Comment: yes, I'm sorry, you can mark answer of Sheikh Heera, it is working

Comment: I'm lucky, your anwser was what I needed to solve other problem. Thks.